# Azure AD b2c Sign in one app and automatically sign in on other app

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, swift5

I am new in Azure world but I have to design something which is I have 2 applications who will use azure AD b2c for authentication and Is it possible in azure where I can sign in one application and other applications automatically sign with the same access token (In iOS I can use keychain sharing to share the information among the applications)?

Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at single sign on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on

Comment: Any update for this issue?